# Why is the answer for this question TRUE?

Tags: reading, test

I really don't get why the answer for this question is true:

> According to recent data about 21% of adult smokers used e-cigarettes in 2015, which is more than double the rate in 2016.

For me "which is more than double" clearly refers to the number of smokers in 2015 and if 2015 is double to 2016 it means there was more smokers in 2015.

I am aware that my thinking is wrong but I really cannot understand why. Even when I paste this sentence into google translate and translate it into Polish the results are exactly the same as my understanding.

Maybe it is some kind of a grammar construction that needs to be explained somehow?

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what you're exactly asking.

Comment: Hello Bart. Welcome. You are absolutely right, the first statement says that more smokers used e-cigarettes in 2015 than 2016. The statement in the box says the exact opposite.  Your thinking is not wrong. It seems there is a misprint in your test. Sir, you should have more confidence in your abilities.

Comment: This might be more appropriate for [ell.se]

Comment: The question is written incorrectly. It clearly states that twice as many people used e-cigarettes in 2015, compared to 2016. That is, the number of smokers went down.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is clear that OP just needs clarification that the question needs altering. The analysis is not an ELU issue.

Answer (score 1):

**I believe the exam question has mistakes in it.**

> According to **recent** data about 21% of adult smokers used e-cigarettes in **2015**, which is more than double the rate in **2016**.

This statement is very strangely worded. Normally you'd talk about the current (or most **recent**) situation, then compare it to a previous (older) situation. That's how time works: it goes forwards.

I believe it contains a typo and the years have been accidentally swapped.

This is consistent with the question, which you now know to be true. It makes most sense as well.

> 1. In 2016 twice as many people used e-cigerattes as in the previous year. TRUE

---

To me, the question is also incorrectly worded. You cannot say "twice as many did something **as in** the previous year". You can say "**than in**" or "**compared to**" the previous year.

Comment: It's not incorrectly worded in British English, "than in" is less correct here. It's a bit like "different from" (Br Eng) as opposed to "different than" (US Eng).

Comment: What makes the original wording (with the typo) strange is not so much that we normally talk about the current situation first (we could do it the other way round), but that the adjective *double* in such contexts tends to be associated with the verb *double*. It is natural to say that some number in a later year is double the number in an earlier year, because we can in such a scenario also say that the number doubled over time; it is unnatural (even if true) to say that the number in an earlier year is double the number in a later year, because we can't say that the number doubled.

Comment: It’s “twice as many smokers” not “people”.  Us non-smokers are people too.

Comment: There is a further complication. The first statement is about the percentage of smokers who use ecigs, The second seems to be about the number of people who use ecigs, If the number of smokers overall had trebled both could be true, but I suppose we know from general background knowledge this hasn't happened.

Answer (score -2):

"According to recent data about 21% of adult smokers used e-cigarettes in 2015, which is more than double the rate in 2016."

Your understanding of this statement is entirely correct, as in the first part they provide the information that "about 21% of adult smokers used e-cigarettes."

They follow this up with "which is more than double the rate in 2016."

The "which is" must be referring to the percentage of "adult smokers using e-cigarettes."

So the following "more than double the rate in 2016."
Must mean that the number of adult smokers in 2015 IS MORE than double the rate in 2016.
Meaning that in 2015 there were more than twice as many adult smokers using e-cigarettes.

**NOW SCRATCH EVERYTHING I JUST SAID**

The part of the statement "which is more than double the rate in 2016." could POSSIBLY mean that-
OF WHICH the percentage of adult smokers in 2015, it is more than double the rate in 2016."

The "It" refers to the percentage, and the statement is saying the percentage is more than double in 2016.

IN 2016 IT IS MORE THAN DOUBLE.

This would mean that there are more than twice as many smokers in 2016.

IN CONCLUSION, The creators of this question worded it incorrectly, and any loss of points because of this question is not justified.

Comment: The second part of this answer needs clarification. What would the meaning of the sentence as **whole** be, according to that alternative interpretation?